# In akka 2.x, is root actor supervised by someone else?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision

Reading the Akka doc : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/AkkaScala.pdf its states in section

```
2.2.1 Hierarchical Structure
The only prerequisite is to know that each actor has exactly one supervisor,
which is the actor that created it.
```

But at the top of the hierarchy tree the parent actor has no supervisor ?

Comment: "It's supervisors all the way up!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very well explained in [akka doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html) (see **The Top-Level Supervisors** section), a little excerpt from it:

[image]

> The root guardian is the grand-parent of all so-called “top-level”
>   actors and supervises all the special actors mentioned in Top-Level
>   Scopes for Actor Paths using the SupervisorStrategy.stoppingStrategy,
>   whose purpose is to terminate the child upon any type of Exception.
>   All other throwables will be escalated … but to whom? Since every real
>   actor has a supervisor, the supervisor of the root guardian cannot be
>   a real actor. And because this means that it is “outside of the
>   bubble”, it is called the “bubble-walker”. This is a synthetic
>   ActorRef which in effect stops its child upon the first sign of
>   trouble and sets the actor system’s isTerminated status to true as
>   soon as the root guardian is fully terminated (all children
>   recursively stopped).